# send and receiving message using smack API

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

I have setup my open fire(jabber server) on local machine with two user testuser1 and testuser2 .using Spark client both users perform chat without any issue,it's nice.

**openfire IP -192.168.1.65**

I want to use smack API(3.3.0) for send and receiving message. i have write sender side code to send message(with testuser1) and tested with Spark client(with testuser2) message received on testuser2 side,but when i try with java code to receive sender message ,i am not able to receive those publish messages.

**Sender.java**

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;

public class Sender 
{

    public static void main(String a[]) throws XMPPException, InterruptedException
    {
         XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection("192.168.1.65");  
         System.out.println(connection);
         connection.connect();
         connection.login("testuser1", "test123");



         Chat chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat("testuser2@sameek", new MessageListener() {

             public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                 // Print out any messages we get back to standard out.
                 System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
             }
         });
         chat.sendMessage("Howdy test1!");

         while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    }





    }

}
```

**Receiver.java**

```
  import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;






public class Receiver
{

    public static void main(String a[]) throws XMPPException,, InterruptedException
    {
         XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection("192.168.1.65");  
         System.out.println(connection);
         connection.connect();
         connection.login("testuser2", "test123");



         Chat chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat("testuser1@sameek", new MessageListener() {

             public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                 // Print out any messages we get back to standard out.
                 System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
             }
         });
         chat.sendMessage("Howdy test2!");

         while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    }





    }

}
```

please help me and suggest if i am following wrong approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem, after following the tutorial here (http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/xmpp-im-with-smack-for-java.html) and this is what I found:

When you create the chat, you chat the user you want to connect to (eg in my case "user1@gbd038"). This works fine if user1 is using a GUI client such as Spark (which presumably has built-in support and/or error handling for this), and user1 will receive the message. This process attaches the messageListener to a chat now associated with "user1@gbd038". However, when I reply from Spark as user1, the chat that smack receives is actually coming through complete with the location tag, eg:

```
Received message 'hi' from user1@gbd038/Spark 2.6.3
```

So it creates a new chat that the application is not listening for (and therefore your application will not receive / print out). I have found two ways to solve this problem:

1. use the location tag when starting the conversation (although this doesn't seem very scalable or robust):

   `xmppManager.sendMessage("Hello mate", "user1@gbd038/Spark 2.6.3");`
2. as Robin suggested, use a ChatManagerListener (which will create a new chat when receiving the reply from user1, which can be forwarded to the messageListener):

   ```
   chatManager = connection.getChatManager();
   messageListener = new MyMessageListener();

   chatManagerListener = new ChatManagerListener() {
       @Override
       public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally) {
           chat.addMessageListener(messageListener);
       }
   };
   chatManager.addChatListener(chatManagerListener);
   ```

Hope that helps someone in the same position!

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a chat and sending a chat message from both ends but not listening for a chat from either. Use a ChatManagerListener to listen for incoming chats from other clients.